# Jboss start - diable following ports 1090 1091 1098 1099 4446 by default

Tags: java, security, jboss, port, firewall

When we start Jboss, ports 1090 1091 1098 1099 4446 are opened by default.

I am told that opening of these ports can be a security issue and we need to close these ports by default.

Is there a way to disable opening of these ports by default?
As I read, these ports are related to RMI/JNDI/Remoting.

e.g

```
<bean class="org.jboss.services.binding.ServiceBindingMetadata">
    <property name="serviceName">jboss:service=Naming</property>
    <property name="bindingName">Port</property>
    <property name="port">1099</property>
    <property name="description">The listening socket for the Naming service</property>
```

Comment: It's possible the ports need to be open in order for JBoss to function correctly. Could you possibly limit who connects to the undesired ports through firewall rules?

Comment: Thanks John, my requirement is not to open the ports itself. We do limit the ports via firewall after deployment.